# query for to know result scheduler jobs in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have many jobs running in my database. There is into all_scheduler_job_run_details table job_name,req_start_date and status.how can I write query for, when last time worked each  jobs what their status was?

```
select job_name ,staus,max(req_start_date) from all_scheduler_job_run_details where owner='ALI' group by job_name
```

this is my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the most recent execution, and assuming the jobs are not running right now, you can probably get away with:

```
select job_name, state, last_start_date
  from all_scheduler_jobs
 where owner = 'ALI'
```